# Script to find the user who does not have uid (User ID) in LDAP server

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, python-ldap

I wrote a python script to find out the users who does not have uid (User ID) in the ldap server but I am getting weird results.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
import csv

server = Server('server', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, 'uid=idmsa,ou=people,ou=auth,o=csun', 'password', auto_bind=True)
# Fetches the given attributes
conn.search('o=csun', '(&(objectclass=person)(!(uid=*)))', attributes=['uidNumber'])

conn.entries
```

Output:

```
DN: cn=proxy,ou=Auth,o=csun - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2021-12-16T02:42:03.581983
, DN: cn=replica,ou=Auth,o=csun - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2021-12-16T02:42:03.582261
, DN: cn=anricd,ou=Proxies,ou=Auth,o=CSUN - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2021-12-16T02:42:03.582403
, DN: cn=bind,ou=proxies,ou=auth,o=csun - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2021-12-16T02:42:03.582494
, DN: cn=ciscovoip,ou=Proxies,ou=Auth,o=CSUN - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2021-12-16T02:42:03.582578
, DN: cn=ecs samba,ou=Proxies,ou=Auth,o=CSUN - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2021-12-
]
```

Comment: What exactly is the `conn.entries` data-structure? What's currently in your question isn't valid Python syntax. What would the correct result be?

Comment: The correct result will be a list of all users who does not have user ID. Everything else is correct I think the olny problem lies in this line            
   conn.search('o=csun', '(&(objectclass=person)(!(uid=*)))', attributes=['uidNumber'])

Comment: That only partial answers what I asked. Of the values shown which one meet that criteria? Also, what data-structure is being shown for the output? Is it a list of strings?

Comment: Yes it's a list of strings

Comment: OK, better…but which part of those strings indicates whether or not the the user has a uid?

Comment: conn.search('o=csun', '(&(objectclass=person)(!(uid=*)))', attributes=['uidNumber'])
This part

Comment: No, no, no…which part of the string you are getting back. Never mind, I give up.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
import csv


# In[5]:
LDAP_SERVER ="ipa.demo1.freeipa.org"
LDAP_USER ="uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org"
LDAP_PASSWORD ="Secret123"
server = Server(LDAP_SERVER, get_info=ALL)


# In[19]:
conn = Connection(server, LDAP_USER, LDAP_PASSWORD, auto_bind=True)

# In[23]:
conn.search('dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org', '(&(objectclass=person)(&(uid=*)))', attributes=['uidNumber'])
conn.entries
```

Here is the result:

```
[DN: uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2021-12-16T10:03:14.011458
     uidNumber: 613800000,
 DN: uid=manager,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2021-12-16T10:03:14.011458
     uidNumber: 613800001,
 DN: uid=employee,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2021-12-16T10:03:14.011458
     uidNumber: 613800003,
 DN: uid=helpdesk,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2021-12-16T10:03:14.011458
     uidNumber: 613800004]
```

​